# Evaluate Path Integral

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Consider the vector field

F=\begin{pmatrix} 
       -3z^2sinx            \\[0.3em]
       8y^3z \\[0.3em]
       2y^4+6zcosx           
     \end{pmatrix}

By evaluating the path integral, compute
$\int\limits_C F.t $ ds where the path C is a straight line that begins at $(3\pi/2,2,-1)$ and ends at the point $(X,Y,Z)$ where $X,Y,Z$ are fixed values.

Now Ive had a go, parametrised the curve to get

$x=3\pi/2(1-t)+Xt$,

$y=2(1-t)+Yt$

$z=-1(1-t)+Zt$

I was wondering where I go from here, simply evaluating $F(x(t),y(t),z(t))$, at least the way I have approached it seems like a lot of work with what I have (plugging in x,y and z) .

So I guess I am asking: Am I correct thus far and what is the best way to continue?

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is correct, but a simple way of doing this

For a scalar field $$S=2y^4z+3z^2cosx$$

F is gradient of S i.e., $F=\bigtriangledown S$

Hence $\int Fdt=\int\bigtriangledown S=S(X,Y,Z)-S(\frac{3\pi}{2}, -2,1)=S(X,Y,Z)-32$